# Remove Default Apps with Configurator 2

Tags: ios, applications, apple-configurator

I've been tasked with creating profiles and blueprints with Configurator 2 for deployment on company owned iPhones.

However, I'm hung up on one problem. I was told to remove some of the default apps, including mail. I figured out how to disable them, but not remove the app entirely using a Configurator profile.

Is there a way to do this? All I'm finding on it are articles from 2016 that do exactly what I did but with vastly different results.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Here you get options to disable iTunes Store, News, Podcast, etc but at the bottom of this window is where you can name specific apps to restrict.

If you change “`Allow All Apps`” to “`Do Not Allow Some Apps`” you can then tap the + button to add apps you don’t require.

Just search for the specific app and select choose.

Once you have added the apps you wish to restrict just close this window and you will be prompted to save the profile.